# Stop a download of Windows 10 Technical Preview for Phones

Tags: update, insider-preview

How does one Stop a download of Windows 10 Technical Preview (10.0.10536.1004) shown wrongly as an update for my HTC8S?
I had enrolled for the Windows Insider and this update was offered and subsequently it was tipped that it is only for eligible phones.
Now I want stop the download and installation. How?

Comment: The update should only be offered to compatible handsets, which does include some HTC handsets.

Comment: It was offered by mistake by MS updates to HTC8S. I started download. Now the point is how to remove/stop this download?

Comment: Only reason the 8S is getting this build is because the build has a problem with the detectoids, Gabe is advising that you reflash your devices as the phone is still unsupported in this build and problems can come up.